# Heap library for Python on PyPI

Tags: library, software-development, python, c

The builtin `heapq` library in Python only supports min-heaps and is implemented in pure python, which makes it quite slow. Is there a decent heap library the supports both min-heaps and max-heaps and is written in C?

Answer (score 1):

Heap functionality is so tiny, it *should* be inlined whenever possible. In python, this means copy&paste (I'm not aware of Python automatically inlining small functions, like Java does).

Whatever library you use, it will come at a non-neglibile invocation overhead. More than just putting the code (specific for your problem) inline. To really improve things, convert your code to Cython then.

Comment: Inlining? This is python.

Comment: Exactly. C++ would do this via templates. But in Python, you need to *manually* inline by copying this tiny function in-place.

Comment: Apparently, CPython contains a C++ implementation too. Wouldn't PyPy or Cython in pure python mode + type annotations be a better solution?

Comment: Copy-and-pasting would reduce speed because it's written in C++

Comment: In C++ it does not matter. You would use a template in C++ which is effectively inlined, too. The compiler can optimize this well once you have safe types. The main bottleneck is due to duck typing.

Comment: I mean the python library is written in C++. You can't inline C++ code into python.